# Plot number of instances forming each group in a seaborn bar plot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

How to easily get the number of instances (males and females) for each day and plot it on top of each bar?

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips)

for p in ax.patches:
             ax.annotate("%.2f" % MISSING_VALUE_TO_PLOT, (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                 ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='gray', xytext=(0, 20),
                 textcoords='offset points')
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidG, no this answer displays the values of the bars, I would like to display the number of males and females on which the statistics are calculated

Comment: I guess you would have to manipulate the pandas dataframe `tips` in order to get that information?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some info on a seaborn plot, my advice is to use `order=` and `hue_order=` so you know in advance in what order the bars are going to be drawn.

Then it's just a matter of crafting a dataframe with the data you need in that same order.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

x_col = 'day'
x_order = ['Fri', 'Thur', 'Sat', 'Sun']
hue_col = 'sex'
hue_order = ['Male','Female'] 

counts = tips.groupby([hue_col, x_col]).size().reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([hue_order,x_order]))

plt.figure()
ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", order=x_order, hue="sex", hue_order=hue_order, data=tips)
for p,c in zip(ax.patches,counts):
             ax.annotate("%d" % c, (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                 ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='gray', xytext=(0, 20),
                 textcoords='offset points')
plt.show()
```

[image]